# Python separate matching string at the end of a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm finding it difficult getting started with regular expressions in python.

I have a bunch of strings now that look like this:

> ```
> <street address><SPACE><#><SPACE><Suite number or letter>
> ```

I need to separate the Suite number from the rest of the string and save it in another variable.  I also need a copy of the street address without the suite number.

Here are some examples:

```
    1111 19th St NW # 200
    1408 U St NW # A
    1509 17th St NW # 1
    1515 14th St NW # 1
    1612 K St NW # 1000
    1700 17th St NW # C
    1900 K St NW # 1200
    1900 M St NW # 200
    6034 Baltimore Ave # 2
    843 Quarry Road # 140
    8455 Colesville Rd # 100
```

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this work for you?

```
s = '1111 19th St NW # 200'
n = s.split('#')[1].strip()

print n
```

http://ideone.com/OnaqX

Answer (score 2):

```
s.split()[-1]
```

This will return the entirety of the string after the last space.

With a few of your strings as examples:

```
>>> L = ["1111 19th St NW # 200",
    "1408 U St NW # A",
    "1509 17th St NW # 1",
    "1515 14th St NW # 1"]
>>> [s.split()[-1] for s in L]
['200', 'A', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure how variable your input can be, but either one of these patterns would grab the suite numbers from the examples you gave:

```
/\w+$/

/\#\s*(\w+)/
```